# Return ID of who has the shortest distance between the coordinates

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I have a function in ajax which returns all latitudes and longitudes of registered users in the database and me of the smallest distance between the returned coordinates and a fixed coordinate the code, works very well it me from the lowest value, problem is that I need to know what that user ID that has the coordinate of shorter distance, I have no idea how to do this, I tried to give a return on the ID but it returns the lowest ID and not the ID less coordinated .

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({


  type : 'POST',
  data : formula,
  url : 'http://10.0.0.119/melleve/statusorig2.php',
  success : function(data){


    var retorno = JSON.parse(data);




var testandoisso = $.map(retorno, function (value) {

  var latitude = value.latitude;
  var longitude = value.longitude;
  var id = value.idmoto;



var lat1 = -22.8650697;
var lat2 = latitude;

var long1 = -43.287510499999996;
var long2 = longitude;

var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
var theta = long1 - long2;
var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
var dist = Math.sin(radlat1)*Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
dist = Math.acos(dist);

dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;


var finaldist = dist * 1.609344;


return finaldist;


});

var ok = Math.min.apply(Math, testandoisso);

     console.log(ok);



  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //debugger;
  }
  //,complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
   // debugger;
  //}

})
```

console.log(ok) writes in the console of my browser the value of the shortest distance, I need it to return me the ID of who has the shortest distance.

already, many thanks to all.

Comment: Be a lot simpler to do distance calculations right in  database query and order query by distance. Then your response would already be sorted

Comment: Thanks for the quick response friend, but I could not quite understand what you mean, show me an example? already I looked enough but I found answer yet.

Comment: can you post your JSON response? You probably just need to include user id next to the latitude and longitude in your JSON response

Comment: my JSON returns the DE variables, latitude and longitude but can not return to which ID belongs to latitude after the calculation why he only returns me the value of the final calculation tried to return the ID in return but it's error and does not return anything to me, this is the problem, but if I just return the ID in return he gives me the lowest ID and not the lower latitude ID